# composite index on large table, optimizing aggregate query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

We are having a large table (Having arround 160 million records) in MySql 5.5.

The machine having 4GB RAM where we installed our mysql

table schema

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| domain        | varchar(50)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| uid           | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sid           | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| vurl          | varchar(2500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip            | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ref           | varchar(2500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stats_time    | datetime      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| country       | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| region        | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| place         | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email         | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Indexes

```
    +------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| visit_views |          1 | sid_index        |            1 | sid         | A         |   157531031 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visit_views |          1 | domain_index     |            1 | domain      | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visit_views |          1 | email_index      |            1 | email       | A         |      392845 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visit_views |          1 | stats_time_index |            1 | stats_time  | A         |    78765515 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Example query

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM visit_views
 WHERE domain ='our'
   AND email!=''
   AND stats_time BETWEEN '2010-06-21 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-21 00:00:00';
```

We are having very slow performance on queries like above, So I want to add composite index on this table

I ran following command

```
ALTER TABLE visit_views ADD INDEX domain_statstime_email (domain,stats_time,email);
```

after running this command , our table got locked, it has reached connection limit (connect limit is 1000). Now table is not responding for any INSERTS and SELECTS.

Here are my few questions

1.Why table got locked and why table is not releasing existing connections

2.How much time it will take to complete the index. I applied 3 hours back still index not created.

3.How to see index creation progress.

4.Why connection limit suddenly increasing to max while adding index to table.

5.Is it safe to add composite indexes for this kind of large table

6.If I add partitions for this table, will it any better performance.

I don't know much about indexes

some stats

```
+---------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size |
+---------------------------+
|                3221225472 |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: The query in your example can only use the first 2 fields of a `domain,stats_time,email` index. To use all 3 you need to have the field with the range condition last (`domain,email,stats_time`).

Comment: What version are you using?  (I am fishing for whether the ALTER was done online or not.)

Comment: We are using MySql 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has three conditions: an inequality, an equality, and a range.

```
WHERE domain ='our'
  AND email!=''
  AND stats_time BETWEEN '2010-06-21 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-21 00:00:00';
```

To make this work, you should try the following indexes to see which one works better.

```
 (email, domain, stats_time)
 (domain, email, stats_time)
```

Why these?  MySQL indexes are BTREE. That is, they're sorted in order. So to satisfy the query MySQL finds the first element in the index matching your query.  That's based on domain, email, and the starting stats_time value. It then scans the index sequentially looking for the last matching value. Along the way it counts the records, and that satisfies your query. In other words it does a range scan on stats_time.

Why the choice?  I don't know what MySQL will do with the inequality in your email matching predicate. That's why I suggest trying both.

**If you have not simplified the query you showed us**, you also might try a [compound covering index](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) on

```
 (domain, stats_time, email)
```

This will random-access immediately to the first matching domain/stats_time combination, and then scan to the last one. As it scans, it will look at the email values from the index (that's why this is called a covering index) and pick out the rows matching. Along the way it counts the rows.

You should consider declaring your `email` column `NOT NULL` to help your inequality test use its index more efficiently.  Read http://use-the-index-luke.com/ for good background information.

As to your questions:

> Why table got locked and why table is not releasing existing connections
>   Why connection limit suddenly increasing to max while adding index to table.

It can take a long time to add an index to a large table. Yours, at 160 megarows, is large. While that indexing operation us going on, other users of the table must wait. So, if you're accessing this from a web app, the connections pile up waiting for it to become available.

> How much time it will take to complete the index. I applied 3 hours back still index not created.

It will be much faster on a quiet system. It is also possible you have some redundant single-column indexes you could drop.  You may wish to copy the table and index the copy, then, when it's ready, rename it.

> How to see index creation progress.

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` will display all the action in your MySQL server. You'll need a command line interface to give this command.

> Is it safe to add composite indexes for this kind of large table

Yes, of course, but it takes time on a production system.

> If I add partitions for this table, will it any better performance.

Probably not. What WILL help is DELETEing rows that are old, if you don't need them.

Comment: In this table 80% 'email' column values are empty but not null. In this case which combination is better (domain_statstime_email) or (domain_email_statstime). I thought first one.

Comment: @Jones Thanks for your comment. Any way to create index faster on this big table??

Comment: The only way to create the index faster is to do it on a quiet MySQL server. You may be able to copy the table, index the copy, then rename the original and the copy. This will allow the original table to stay in service while you index the copy.